# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of null

Tags: focus, ref

I'm trying to use react-to-print library, but seems ref function has a problem.

I'm using react version `15.6.1`.

Is there any other ways to use ref?

Here's my code:

```
return (
  <div>
    <ReactToPrint
      trigger={() => <a href='#'>Хэвлэх</a>}
      content={() => this.componentRef}
    />
    <div ref={el => (this.componentRef = el)}>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div style={styles.container}>
                {this.renderProblems()}
          </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Check this - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: What is this - `content={() => this.componentRef}`? What you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to print things contained in <MuiThemeProvider> as pdf. content={() => this.componentRef} is a ReactToPrint library`s basic code to take content i want to print, i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine without any issues, see working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-to-print-sgks9)

Try removing node_modules and installaing the dependencies again that might solve your issue and if issue still persist please share more details so it can be investigated further.